# allow any character in htaccess query string validation (non-English characters)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, non-latin

I'm having this htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-_]+)
/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ page.php?lang=$1&search=$2&state_type=$3&city=$4
&stats=$5&area=$6&cost=$7 [NC,L]
```

The fourth query string is in Arabic and I want to allow any characters as long as [0-9a-zA-Z_-] will validate against English characters only. When I use (.*) it allows any English characters but when I insert Arabic characters I get a 404 error. So how to allow any characters in htaccess validation rule to get Arabic values?

[UPDATE]
Changed the htaccess rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?lang=$1&search=$2&
state_type=$3&city=$4&stats=$5&area=$6&cost=$7 [NC,L]
```

Now I don't get the 404 error but when I echo the query string value (which is in Arabic) I get empty value and when I change it to English it works fine. I've tried to change all the query string values to Arabic and got the same result: empty as it's not there at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ page.php?lang=$1&search=$2&state_type=$3&city=$4&stats=$5&area=$6&cost=$7 [B,NC,L]
```

`.` is too greedy so just look for anything that's not a `/`. The `B` flag turns decoded characters back into escaped ones suitable for a query string.

Comment: still empty value. I have this code before it does it make any porblem? RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arab-aqar\.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC] RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arab-aqar\.com [NC] RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} # to use home instead of index.php RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC,L] – PHP User 41 mins ago   edit

Comment: Open up your network panel in your browser's debugger to see the actual request headers being sent. Are you putting all 7 parameters into your test URL? They're all required for the rule to match. `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_GET);` at the start of `page.php` to see what URL it's seeing and what query string parameters have been set by your rule.

Comment: string(90) "/page/ar/search/10/cairo/for_rent/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A" array(7) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "ar" ["search"]=> string(6) "search" ["state_type"]=> string(2) "10" ["city"]=> string(5) "cairo" ["stats"]=> string(8) "for_rent" ["area"]=> string(8) "عربي" ["cost"]=> string(8) "عربي" }

Comment: echo $area = '<br>area '.filter_text(preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]#i', '', $_GET['area']));    

echo $cost = '<br>cost: '.filter_text(preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z-]#i', '', $_GET['cost']));

Result is empty

Comment: changed to
    echo $area = '<br>area '.preg_replace('#[^/]#i', '', $_GET['area']);
                    echo $cost = '<br>cost: '.preg_replace('#[^/]#i', '', $_GET['cost']);
And still empty nothing to echo

Comment: after removing preg_replace and just keep $_GET['cost'] I get the correct value. I don't have much knowledge in htaccess and clean URL but know that I had to use preg_replace to save the new sent value to the page